# Typescript interface property as nested keys of generic objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Based on the following structure:

```
interface ApiEntity {
  [key: string]: number | string;
}

interface ApiData {
  [key: string]: ApiEntity;
}

interface Entity1 extends ApiEntity {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface Entity2 extends ApiEntity {
  uuid: string;
  description: string;
}

interface MyData extends ApiData {
  a: Entity1;
  b: Entity2;
}
```

How can I create an interface that would accept only a valid entity and property:

```
// The problem
interface DataFields<T extends ApiData> {
  label: string;
  entity: keyof T; // ensure that entity is one of the properites of abstract ApiData
  property: keyof keyof T; // ensure that property is one of the properties of ApiEntity
  other?: string;
}
```

So the created fields are safe and TS shows errors when invalid:

```
const fields: MyDataFields<MyData>[] = [{
  label: 'A ID',
  entity: 'a', // valid
  property: 'id', // valid
},{
  label: 'B Description',
  entity: 'b', // valid
  property: 'description', // valid
},{
  label: 'Invalid',
  entity: 'c', // TS Error
  property: 'name', // TS Error
}];
```

Or even better:

```
const MyDataFields: DataField<MyData>[] = [
  {label: 'A ID', entityProperty: 'a.id'},
  {label: 'B Description', entityProperty: 'b.description'},
  {label: 'Invalid', entityProperty: 'c.name'}, // TS Error
];
```

Comment: `ApiData` is declared to allow any key as a string, and `MyData` extends `ApiData`, so how can `c` be inferred as an invalid property name? The interface says *every* string is a valid property name. The same applies for `Entity1` and `Entity` which extend `ApiEntity`, where the latter says every string is a valid property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the interface hierarchy you've defined, where `ApiData` and `ApiEntity` are declared to allow *any string* as a property name, there is simply no way for Typescript to infer that `c` is not a valid property name for `MyData` or that `name` is not a valid property name for `Entity2`. On the contrary, Typescript will infer that these *are* valid property names because of how the interfaces are declared:

```js
function foo(obj: Entity1): void {
  // no type error
  console.log(obj.foo);
}
function bar(obj: MyData): void {
  // no type error
  console.log(obj.bar);
}
```

But this problem can be solved if you get rid of `ApiData` and `ApiEntity`, or at least narrow them to not allow all strings as property names.

The valid values for `property` depend on the value of `entity`, so this needs to be a discriminated union type where `entity` is the discriminant. We can construct it using a mapped type:

```js
interface Entity1 {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface Entity2 {
  uuid: string;
  description: string;
}

interface MyData {
  a: Entity1;
  b: Entity2;
}

type DataFields<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    label: string,
    entity: K,
    property: keyof (T[K])
  }
}[keyof T]
```

Examples:

```js
const fields: DataFields<MyData>[] = [{
  label: 'A ID',
  entity: 'a', // OK
  property: 'id', // OK
}, {
  label: 'B Description',
  entity: 'b', // OK
  property: 'description', // OK
}, {
  label: 'Invalid',
  // Type error: 'c' is not assignable to 'a' | 'b'
  entity: 'c',
  property: 'name',
}, {
  label: 'Invalid',
  entity: 'a',
  // Type error: 'foo' is not assignable to 'id' | 'name' | 'uuid' | 'description'
  property: 'foo',
},
// Type error: 'id' is not assignable to 'uuid' | 'description'
{
  label: 'Invalid',
  entity: 'b',
  property: 'id',
}];
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=48&ssc=4&pln=24&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAngRmQbwChllgATALmRAFcBbAI2gG5jq46IqBnMKUAOasAvoUKhIsRCnRhMWAEwE2NGuR59BrEmQjcE-AA5yA9iA38QQwqPHho8JMgCyWACJwwcZSThVZ8jjayAz+GNgKImLYhigeXgBiwBAANmTcADwAKgB8yAC8PsgA2gDSpCDIANYQWCYwyFkAulREJCQpcEwpFoIANGwkEOFYVKUD7ciGUCaxUNhUNXUNABRZZU0AlGyiwsVL9Y1NYghmvMgwyWncVPFwSanpGa53OcVNBSVtyJ3dVADkAEFkABJNz-CbIYZyBbIf5wCHIAD0SOQAHlSmxprNoLD-uRESj0ZjhH0ir9UgCAELINx6AzAYzAMwQtjQ+QAhiE1EYrEzOZ43T6IymEDc4k2MnfCk9OEgkAANzgKQJkKJWSwsShUBmUABCH+pG41BMYGQcG43GAAhAXRSKDAJjhCOQAB84Vy2SN9aySNiBaM4bbOKzSeSupS5YrlaqvTDA-DfcjURqtdBdQCYCYTIbgMaQKbzZbrbaGPbkI64QS3UGOBBDe7-qpq42hQymSy+Tj5gmszmBqTCOrNSh0yY9VWyLn84WLVabXaHU6m2opzX-m2RcyxYRpRHZf95UqVVPIey8VzIf7cQnY8ImswgA)